# WSO2 human task goes to COMPLETED state but calling BPEL process remains in ACTIVE state

Tags: wso2, bpel, asynchronous, human-interface

I have created WSO2 human task as per the guidelines mentioned in link (http://docs.wso2.org/display/BPS300/Writing+a+Human+Task+Artifact). 
I am calling human task from Asynchronous BPEL process, once human task get completed it proceeds further with other BPEL Activities and callback client.
I am facing an issue i.e. Human task goes to COMPLETED task state but my BPEL Process which is calling that human task is not proceeding further from REMOTE TASK Activity to next BPEL activity and it remains in ACTIVE state.
Please suggest what needs to be done for that, do I need to use BPEL correlation for that, If yes then how do I implement co-relation in human task activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. you don't need to use BPEL correlation in BPEL process for Remote Task. B4P extension correlates BPEL instance and Task instance internally. For this B4P extension uses a correlation filter in deploy.xml file.

Seems like above part is missing in the documentation. I will update the document. In the meantime can you follow following step to fix it.

1) Open deploy.xml in text/xml editor.

2) Let's say your task's partner link is `b4pPartnerLink`. Then find provider service for `b4pPartnerLink` partner link and add correlation filter `correlationFilter="b4p:b4pFilter"` as follow.

```
<provide partnerLink="b4pPartnerLink" correlationFilter="b4p:b4pFilter">
    <service name="apprv:ClaimServiceCB" port="ClaimPortCB"/>
</provide>
```

Example : http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/products/bps/3.1.0/modules/samples/product/src/main/resources/bpel/2.0/ClaimsApprovalProcess/deploy.xml

3) Then Re deploy bpel process.

If the problem still exists, can you please check whether Callback service url is correct in the WSDL.

Thanks ~ hasitha

Comment: Hi @hasitha , is it possible to get the task id(task created by process) in the bpel process?