# Is there any HUMAN TASK UI in BPS OR BPEL in WSO2

Tags: wso2, bpel, wso2-data-services-server, apache-ode, wso2-esb

Hi i am working on WSO2 BPS 3.1.0 with samples given by BPS server.  While i am deploying these sample in Eclipse.i am able to see only BPEL Editor and WSDL Editor.

But i didn't see any other UI for HUMANTASK in Eclipse or in Wso2. Even i didn't find any learning document for HUMANTASK except this

http://docs.wso2.org/display/BPS310/Writing+a+Human+Task+Artifact

is there any UI for HumanTask and its end to end document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for HumanTask editor:- No, Currently `WSO2 DevStudio` doesn't have a Humantask editor. But you can use DevStudio's xml editor to edit humantask file (`.ht`).

`WSO2 BPS` supports Humantask 1.1 specification [1]. Currently it only supports remote humantask and remote notifications. Subtasks, lean tasks, inline Humantasks are not supported at the moment. If you want to learn humantask, I prefer specification [0]. It is a very simple specification compare to the BPEL 2.0. http://docs.wso2.org/display/BPS310/Writing+a+Human+Task+Artifact covers basic syntax required for humantask. I have written some blog posts to cover some advance humantask usecases. [1],[2]

**Some useful tips for editing .ht files:**

- set `.ht` file association for xml editor.
- As mentioned in [3] set .ht file with humantask xsd [4] for xml validation and auto-fill function based on xsd.

[0] http://docs.oasis-open.org/bpel4people/ws-humantask-1.1-spec-cs-01.html

[1] http://tryitnw.blogspot.com/2013/05/escalating-human-task-with-wso2-bps.html

[2] http://tryitnw.blogspot.com/2013/05/humantask-event-listeners-wso2-bps.html

[3] http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.xmleditor.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Fcxmlcat.html

[4] http://docs.oasis-open.org/bpel4people/ws-humantask.xsd

Also refer this stack-overflow question as well. [WSO2 human task goes to COMPLETED state but calling BPEL process remains in ACTIVE state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509402/wso2-human-task-goes-to-completed-state-but-calling-bpel-process-remains-in-acti/19534689#19534689)

Comment: Hi Hasitha,Is there any deadline or Escalation expression in WSO2 BPS(BPEL) Server 3.1.0..